# How to use calendarView

Tags: android, calendar, android-studio, calendarview

I am trying to create month-view by using calendarView. But I miss some experience with calendarView. I actually just know how I can change the colours. 
I want that the user can just see the current month and cant scroll through the calendar etc.

Do you know any usefull documentations, tutorials or handy tips, thereby I could handle calendarView a little bit more profassionally?

Comment: Check this custom calender and try to modify as per your requirement 1.https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid 2. http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi visit all given links, hope will help you

1.https://github.com/inteist/android-better-time-picker

2.https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers

3.http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2013/05/android-calendar-sync.html

4.http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/extendedcalendarview/

5.http://abinashandroid.wordpress.com/2013/07/21/how-to-create-custom-calendar-in-android/

6.http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/

7.https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

8.https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker

when you will visit

https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers

For a working implementation of this project see the sample/ folder.

Implement the appropriate Handler callbacks:

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity implements DatePickerDialogFragment.DatePickerDialogHandler {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onDialogDateSet(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    // Do something with your date!
  }
}
```

Use one of the Builder classes to create a PickerDialog with a theme:

```
DatePickerBuilder dpb = new DatePickerBuilder()
.setFragmentManager(getSupportFragmentManager())
.setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment);
dpb.show()
```

also for an another example you can visit

https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

and use as follows

To embed the caldroid fragment in your activity, use below code:

```
CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
t.replace(R.id.calendar1, caldroidFragment);
t.commit();
```

Comment: Thats a lot of links! The least code example would have been enough, but thanks a lot.